# What is the value of 5 | 3 in C?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, boolean-logic, bitwise-or

According to boolean algebra, 5 is equivalent to 101 in binary. And 3 is equivalent to 011. So if we calculate 101 | 011 then it should be 1000 which is equivalent to 2^3 = 8 but in vs code the compiler gives 7, is there any error in my solution?

Comment: How do you deduce that binary `101 | 011` should be `1000`?  What do you understand the `|` (bitwise or) operator to do?  You need to read the section in your textbook that explains how the bitwise operators in C work.

Comment: It doesn't add.

Comment: read up on [bitwise OR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR) (even uses 5 and 3 as an example)

Comment: Boolean algebra has nothing to do with the fact that 5 (base 10) is 101(base 2).  Boolean algebra tells you that 101 | 011 is 111.  And boolean algebra again has nothing to do with the fact that 111(base 2) is 7(base 10)

Answer (score 1):

According to the C Standard (6.5.12 Bitwise inclusive OR operator)

> 4 The result of the | operator is the bitwise inclusive OR of the
> operands (that is, each bit in the result is set if and only if at
> least one of the corresponding bits in the converted operands is set).

So you have

```
 101
|
 011
====
 111
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do the or operation for individual bits, as 1|0=1,1|1=1,0|1=1,0|0=0.

```
for 5,the value in bits=1 0 1
for 3,the value in bits=0 1 1
                        ------
                        1 1 1,which is 7.
```